# Linux File Permission 0070 - Group RWX

Tags: linux, permissions

A friend of mine set permissions on a file that he owns to 0070. He's in the group. Basically, he wants the group to have rwx, but not the file owner. When he tries to cat or vi the file, he gets permission denied. Do the user bits have to be set for the file owner in order for group members to read and write the file?

```
chmod 0070 test.txt 
cat test.txt 
cat: test.txt: Permission denied


chmod 0670 test.txt 
cat test.txt 
test
123
```

Comment: Your display is incomplete and will prevent any of su from helping you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If he is the "owner" of the file... and "o" has 0 for it's permission bits... that means he has no rights to the file.  Group bits won't be evaluated unless he is not the owner.  `chown` the file to another user (perhaps `nobody`?) and then the group bits will apply.  (of course... this does not apply to root)  If he is indeed the owner, keep in mind that he can always change permissions back.